# When are parentheses required for sub calls in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would've expected all of these to print out 1, 2 and 3. But the last two  don't. Why is that?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub mysub {
    return (1,2,3);
}

print "--- foreach (mysub()) prints 1, 2 and 3\n";
foreach (mysub()) {
    print $_, "\n";
}

print "--- foreach (mysub) prints 1, 2 and 3\n";
foreach (mysub) {
    print $_, "\n";
}

print "--- foreach (sort(mysub())) prints 1, 2 and 3\n";
foreach (sort(mysub())) {
    print $_, "\n";
}

print "--- foreach (sort mysub()) prints no elements (huh?)\n";
foreach (sort mysub()) {
    print $_, "\n";
}

print "--- foreach (sort mysub) prints a single 'mysub' string (huh?)\n";
foreach (sort mysub) {
    print $_, "\n";
}
```

It has this output:

```
--- foreach (mysub()) prints 1, 2 and 3
1
2
3
--- foreach (mysub) prints 1, 2 and 3
1
2
3
--- foreach (sort(mysub())) prints 1, 2 and 3
1
2
3
--- foreach (sort mysub()) prints no elements (huh?)
--- foreach (sort mysub) prints a single 'mysub' string (huh?)
mysub
```

Why not 1, 2 and 3 in every case? (Perl 5.18.2 on debian jessie)

Comment: While this looks like a duplicate question, I respectfully suggest that in fact is is not a duplicate of any of the three questions marked above. (I did in fact read every single one of them before posting). As @ikegami points out in his answer, this root cause is really about `sort`. My first two test cases illustrate that `mysub` and `mysub()` behave identically.

Comment: Re-opened. None of the three questions of which this was supposedly a dup have anything to do with `sort`.

Comment: @stevieb, Operator names aren't reserved words in Perl, merely keywords. (e.g. `sub print { }`, `sub and { }`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for sort is:

- `sort SUBNAME LIST`
- `sort BLOCK LIST`
- `sort LIST`

The first is really weird and the source of the problems such as yours.

---

**`sort mysub()`**

`sort SUBNAME LIST` uses the sub named `SUBNAME` to sort the list, so `sort mysub ()` asks `sort` to sort an empty list.

---

**`sort mysub`**

Here, Perl again thinks you're going for `sort SUBNAME LIST` until it finds no `LIST`. Having been provided something incorrect, it guesses the string it considered to be a sub name must have been meant to be the list of items to sort.

This situation could be handled better —why would Perl assume you wanted to sort a single constant item?— but the resolution makes more sense when you consider the following:

```
$ perl -le'my $s = abc; print $s;'
abc

$ perl -le'my ($s) = sort abc; print $s;'
abc
```

---

**Solutions**

- `sort(mysub())`<sup>[1]</sup>
- `sort +mysub()`
- `sort +mysub`

---

1. That parens can't be used with the `SUBNAME` syntax is rather odd in and of itself. They can be used for the `BLOCK` syntax (e.g. `sort( { $a cmp $b } @a )`), and they can be used for in other functions that accept a leading identifier (e.g. `print(STDOUT "abc\n");`).

Comment: I just noticed in testing if you do `sort mysub, mysub`, it does the right thing on the first `mysub`, but not the second: `123mysub`. I didn't realize until I tested that, that it was a `sort` thing and not a perl thing.